# How do i tell Amazon that a seller betrays the customers?

Tags: amazon

I found some sellers that betray their customers.

I ordered a router at each of them: TP-Link **TL-WR841ND** but they are all sending another revision of the same router instead, that costs a few dollars less new: TP-Link **TL-WR841N**

Is there a way to contact Amazon to tell them this is going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can report Sellers who violate Amazons TOS at the following link:

http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/reports/contact-us

Comment: how did you find that link? I cannot find it in the english amazon help pages.

Comment: in German Amazon the contact can be made here: https://www.amazon.de/gp/help/contact-us/